# How can I use Microsoft Graph API to list folders in SharePoint?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How can i list the folders in SharePoint ?

I have tried the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists
```

But this does not seem to give back the Groups from which i can then drill down to get the folders and documents.

Do i need to get Groups first and then get the id of the group and then drill down?

Comment: can [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/290907) help you?

Comment: @TinyWang Should this post be migrated to that stack exchange site?

Comment: I'm not very sure, I haven't seen anyone vote this case as a duplicated question..